Change namespace with Jaxb2Marshaller
In my config spring boot have this:
@Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.system.ws");

        
  

        return marshaller;
    }

My SOAP ENVELOPE has
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

I need change to:
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">

How do this?

You don't as that has nothing to do with the marshaller but by the Soap version you are using.
